# Spark Structured Streaming Aggregation Output Interval

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I'm reviewing the [StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredNetworkWordCountWindowed.scala) example in Apache Spark Structured Streaming and am having trouble finding information about how I can update the example to control the output intervals. When I run the example I receive output every time a micro batch is processed. I understand that this is intended because the main case is to process data and emit results in real time but what about the case where I want to process data in real time but output the state at some specific interval? Does Spark Structured Streaming support this scenario? I reviewed the programming guide and the only similar concept that is mentioned is the Trigger.ProcessingTime option. Unfortunately, this option is not quite what is needed since it applies to the batch processing time and the scenario described above still requires processing data in real time.

Is this feature supported? More specifically, how do I only output the state at the time the window ends assuming there are no late arrivals and using a tumbling window?

Comment: Please provide some input and expected output.

Comment: consuming in real time and output the state once in a while sounds like a window aggregation